# How to combine 03 SELECT statements / MySQL queries for single MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I am looking to extract from a single MySQL table:

1. Send emails to users whose birthday is today and have birthdays in the next 06 days.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table_01
WHERE  DATE_ADD(date_of_birth, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(date_of_birth)
       + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) = DAYOFYEAR(date_of_birth),1,0) YEAR) 
    BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY);
```

2. Send emails to the users who are only 01 year / 365 days old.

Query:

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date_of_registration, NOW()) 
 FROM table_01 
 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date_of_registration, NOW()) = 365;
```

3. Send emails to the users who are male.

   `SELECT * FROM  table_01 where gender = male;`

I have used JOIN, UNION commands but still not working.

Please advice.

Comment: Could you add your tables schema to have a better idea...

Comment: No need for joins, unions, etc. Simple combine the 3 where clause conditions with an OR

Comment: `where gender = male` that is already failing here; quote string literals.

Comment: The number of selected columns must be equal for all three queries if you want to use UNION. In the second query you are selecting one more column (`TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date_of_registration, NOW())`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *,
    IF(DATE_ADD(`date_of_birth`, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`date_of_birth`) + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) = DAYOFYEAR(`date_of_birth`),1,0) YEAR) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY),1,0) as `matchtype1`,
    IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, `date_of_registration`, NOW()) = 365,1,0) as `matchtype2`,
    IF(`gender` = 'male',1,0) as `matchtype3`
FROM `table_01`
WHERE (DATE_ADD(`date_of_birth`, INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`date_of_birth`) + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) = DAYOFYEAR(`date_of_birth`),1,0) YEAR) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY))
    AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,`date_of_registration`, NOW()) <= 365)
    AND (`gender` = 'male')
ORDER BY `date_of_registration`;
```

Comment: Thanks Sloan Thrasher. I am near to it. But this is also returning users whose date of birth is in current week and have registered before 365 days. I am looking for: Users whose birthday is today and in next 06 days, but those who have registered within last 365 days only, and those are males.

Comment: That wasn't clear in your question. You had 3 separate queries, and you said you just wanted to combine the results. If I understand correctly, now you want the exclusive intersection of those three queries. Also, one doesn't seem to be correct - the registered within last 365. In your query, it is registered 365 days ago (ie 364 and 366 would fail to be included).

Comment: I've edited the answer to match your most recent requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I fully understand the need. (I was following until the gender bit.) I don't have your schema, so this is untested.

```
 SELECT *
  ,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,date_of_birth,GETDATE()) / 365.25) AS AGE_NOW
  ,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,date_of_birth,GETDATE() + 6) / 365.25) AS AGE_SIX_DAYS_FROM_NOW
  ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date_of_registration, NOW()) AS ACCOUNT_AGE
FROM "table_01" EMP
WHERE 1 = (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.date_of_birth,GETDATE()+7) / 365.25))
          -
          (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(dd,EMP.date_of_birth,GETDATE()) / 365.25))
          OR (ACCOUNT_AGE = 365)
          OR (EMP.gender = 'male');
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION is not warking because the second query is return one column more then the other queries :

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date_of_registration, NOW()) 
 FROM table_01 
 WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date_of_registration, NOW()) = 365;
```

so you need to add a column to the other queries or remove the second column.

and you are using one table in all queries why three queries just use one and use or

```
select 
    *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, date_of_registration, NOW())
  from table_01 where 
 (condition of the first query)
   or 
 (condition of the second query)
  or 
(condition of the third query)
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using two ";", maybe that's the problem.

```
SELECT SUM(...) AS AEROWiz
FROM ...

UNION

SELECT SUM(...) AS AEROWiz
FROM ...
```

You could also combine 1st and 3rd sql statement by using AND|OR

Comment: What/why are you summing?